# Given n integer a1, a2, ..., an and k. How many subarrays length k that those elements can construct a triangle?

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a set of distinct positive integers, let's say that it can "construct a triangle" if it can be partitioned into three subsets whose sums can be the lengths of the three sides of a triangle (that is: three subsets whose sums satisfy the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)). For example, { 1, 2, 3, 4 } can "construct a triangle" by partitioning it into { { 1, 2 }, 3, 4 }, because a triangle can have side-lengths 1+2, 3, and 4 (because 1+2 + 3 > 4, 1+2 + 4 > 3, and 3 + 4 > 1+2).

I'm given an array *A* of up to 10<sup>5</sup> distinct nonnegative integers in the range [0, 10<sup>9</sup>] and an integer *k*, and I need to find how many *contiguous* subarrays of length *k* can construct triangles. For example, if *A* = [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 9] and *k* = 3, then there are two such subarrays: [3, 4, 2] and [4, 2, 5].

I've tried the following approach:

- Iterate over *A*, examining each contiguous subarray of length *k*.

  - For each such subarray, find every partition of it into three subsets.

    - For each such partition, calculate the sums of the three subsets, and check whether they satisfy the triangle inequality.
- Return the number of subarrays where the check passed for at least one partition.

This gives the right answer, but it takes O(3<sup>*k*</sup>*n*) time, where *n* is the length of *A*.

I've read about an O(*n*) algorithm for this problem, but I don't understand why it works:

- Iterate over *A*, examining each contiguous subarray of length *k*.

  - For each such subarray, determine its sum *S* and its greatest element *a*<sub>*G*</sub>, then check if *S* > 2a<sub>*G*</sub>.

    - Note #1: The subarray can construct a triangle if and only if this is the case.
    - Note #2: the sums of all subarrays can be determined in O(*n*) time by using prefix sums.
    - Note #3: the greatest elements of all subarrays can be determined in O(*n*) time by using a deque.
- Return the number of subarrays where the check passed for at least one partition.

I was given this explanation for Note #1:

- Let *i* be the first index of the subarray, and *j* be its last index (such that *j* = *i* + *k* − 1).
- Imagine that we've sorted the elements of the subarray, so that *A*<sub>*i*</sub> < *A*<sub>*i+1*</sub> < … < *A*<sub>*j*</sub>.
- Imagine partitioning the subarray as follows:

  - *x* = *A*<sub>*i*</sub> + *A*<sub>*i*+2</sub> + … + *A*<sub>*j*−2</sub>
  - *y* = *A*<sub>*i*+1</sub> + *A*<sub>*i*+3</sub> + … + *A*<sub>*j*−1</sub>
  - z = *A*<sub>*j*</sub>
- It can be easily proved that y + z > x and x + z > y; so to check if it satisfies the triangle inequality, all that remains is to check if x + y > z, which is equivalent to checking if x + y + z > 2z.
- But we can check this without actually sorting: x + y + z is the sum of the entire subarray, and z is its greatest element.

What I don't understand is — this explanation shows that if we partition the subarray in a specific way, then that partition satisfies the triangle equality if and only if x + y + z > 2z. But what if we partition the subarray in a different way? Even if this partition doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality, can't there be a different one that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle inequality can be restated as (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Mathematical_expression_of_the_constraint_on_the_sides_of_a_triangle)

```
x+y+z > 2 max(x,y,z)
```

For any partitioning choice for `x`,`y` and `z`, we have `max(x,y,z) >= A_j`. So if the partitioning you have described

> x = A<sub>i</sub> + A<sub>i+2</sub> + … + A<sub>j−2</sub>
>
> y = A<sub>i+1</sub> + A<sub>i+3</sub> + … + A<sub>j−1</sub>
>
> z = A<sub>j</sub>

does not satisfy the inequality (i.e. `x+y+z > 2A_j` does not hold) then any other partitioning will not satisfy it either.